# Solution of $\dot{X}(t) = A X(t)B $

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A, B, X_0 \in M_{n, n}(\mathbb{R})$. What is the solution to the following differential equation ?

$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        X(0) = X_0 \\
        \dot{X}(t) = A \cdot X(t) \cdot B
    \end{array}
\right.
$

If $A, B$ and $X_0$ commute, we find easily $X(t) = X_0 \exp\left(A\cdot B\;t\right)$ but in a more general setup I didn't find anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that reuns' answer has already been accepted, but here is a derivation (too long for a comment) of his solution, which doesn't need any assumptions on $A$ and $B$.

After integrating directly the original differential equation, i.e.
$$
X(t)-X_0 = \int_{X_0}^{X(t)}\mathrm{d}X = \int_0^t AX(s)B\,\mathrm{d}s,
$$
one understands that the solution can be expanded with the help of this recursive formula; indeed, we get :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
X(t) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   X_0 + \int_0^t AX(s)B\,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   X_0 + \int_0^t A\left(X_0 + \int_0^s AX(s')B\,\mathrm{d}s'\right)B\,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   X_0 + \int_0^t AX_0B\,\mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s_1\int_0^{s_1}\mathrm{d}s_2 \,A^2X(s_2)B^2 \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \ldots \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s_1 \int_0^{s_1}\mathrm{d}s_2 \cdots \int_0^{s_{n-1}}\mathrm{d}s_n \,A^nX_0B^n \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} A^nX_0B^n
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$X(t)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{t^n}{n!} A^n X_0 B^n$$
Not the general case but assume that $A,B$ are diagonalizable. Take an eigenvector $B v = \lambda v$, decompose $X_0v$ in the basis of $A$'s eigenvectors that is
$X_0 v=\sum_{j=1}^n w_j,A w_j= \ell_j w_j$. Then $$X(t) v =
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{t^n}{n!} A^n X_0 B^n v=
\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{t^n}{n!} A^n X_0 \lambda^n v  =  \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{\lambda^n t^n}{n!}A^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_j $$ $$ = \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{ \lambda^n t^n}{n!} \sum_{j=1}^n \ell_j^n w_j = 
\sum_{j=1}^n \exp(\lambda \ell_j t) w_j
$$

---

Without assuming that $A,B$ are diagonalizable:

For $v$ an eigenvector of $B$, $A$ doesn't need to be diagonalizable if we are satisfied with $X(t)v=\exp(\lambda A t) X_0v$. Then if $B\in M_k(\Bbb{C}) $ is not diaongalizable we can write $B=P (\Lambda+N) P^{-1}$ with $\Lambda$ diagonal, $N^k=0$ and $N\Lambda=\Lambda N$. Then $B^n P e_j = P\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {n \choose m}\Lambda_{jj}^{n-m} N^m e_j$ so $$X(t)Pe_j = 
\sum_{n\ge 0}t^n A^n \sum_{m=0}^{\min(k-1,n)}\frac1{m! (n-m)!} \Lambda_{jj}^{n-m} X_0 N^m P e_j$$ $$=
\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} t^m A^m \exp(A \Lambda_{jj} t)\frac1{m!} X_0 P N^m e_j$$

Comment: Note that your answer doesn't need the assumption of diagonalizability for $A$ and $B$; it is true in general and be obtained by recursive integration, i.e. 
$$
X(t) = X_0 + A\int_0^t X(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\,B,
$$
since $A,B$ are constant matrices.

Comment: @Abezhiko Your comment is strange. See my edit.

Comment: I'm just saying that your solution is correct and that it can be recovered by recursive integration of the original differential equation (or by checking it as an ansatz), such that all that diagonal/non-diagonal stuff is unnecessary.

Comment: @Abezhiko I don't see what you mean precisely, please show us your solution

Comment: I've provided my solution, you can look it up below.

Comment: @Abezhiko My answer is giving a closed-form for $X(t)$, not a proof of $X(t)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} A^nX_0B^n$

Comment: Yeah, sure, but that's not a bad thing to show how to derive it, that is why I commented, in order to put the finishing touch to your answer, not to criticize it - I even upvoted it, contrary to "someone" who pettily downvoted mine...

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions for this matrix-valued differential equation. Assuming that both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable with diagonal matrices $D_A$ and $D_B$, respectively, one has

$$
\dot{Y}(t)=D_AY(t)D_B
$$
where $Y(t)=PX(t)Q^{-1}$, $D_A=PAP^{-1}$ and $D_B=QBQ^{-1}$. From there, one can use the ideas proposed in reuns' answer to obtain

$$
X(t)=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{t^n}{n!}X_0\circ a_nb_n^T
$$
where $a_n,b_n$ are vectors containing the diagonal entries of $D_A^n$ and $D_B^n$, respectively.

We can also use vectorization to get
$$
\mathrm{vec}(\dot{X}(t))=(B^T\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(X(t)),
$$
which leads to
$$ 
\mathrm{vec}(X(t))=\exp((B^T\otimes A)t)\mathrm{vec}(X(0)).
$$